# How to fix LazyInitializationException - no Session in Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

In Spring application sometimes I have exception: `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role ... could not initialize proxy - no Session` on `client.getCatIdSet`. I can't test `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` fix problem or not, because this error occurs not constantly. Class have `Transactional` annotation, method is public. How I can fix this exception?

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class ChatService {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public BotRequest getBotRequest(MessageData messageData) {
        Client client = messageData.getMessage().getClient();
        Optional<CatId> mbCatId = Optional.ofNullable(client.getCatIdSet())
                .orElse(Collections.emptySet())
                .filter
                ...
```

This method invoke from:

```java
@Service
public class SendMsgToCatBotService extends SendMsgToBotService {
    @Override
    protected BotRequest createBotRequest(MessageData messageData) {
        return chatService.getBotRequest(messageData);
    }
```

Client entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private Set<CatId> catIdSet;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "clients_generation")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "clients_generation", sequenceName = "clients_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    public Set<CatId> getCatIdSet() {
        return catIdSet;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your web.xml, add below filter.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```